# Is there an accommodations website centered around trading stays?

Tags: airbnb, couchsurfing, homestay

When Airbnb came on the scene, it seemed many (including myself) used it to make travel less expensive.  But it has become increasingly popular for hosts to use it as a significant income source (also driving many cities to impose legislation against it to prevent neighborhood disruptions and rises in housing costs).

Couchsurfing.com has long existed as a more casual, unstructured option.

But are there any websites that are centered around stay swapping or a credit-based system for homestays?  Such a system would seem to facilitate cheaper travel and encourage many of the positives (social interactions, organic city experiences, maximizing housing usage) Airbnb favored without some of the negatives.

Comment: It's usually called "home trading" or "home swap".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of home swapping sites, some examples of which are listed in the article [10 things you need to know about home swapping](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/advice/2013/01/30/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-home-swapping/1877345/):

- [Love Home Swap](http://www.lovehomeswap.com/)
- [Knok](http://www.knok.com/)
- [Homelink](https://homelink.org/en/)
- [Home Exchange](https://www.homeexchange.com/en/)
- [Intervac](https://us.intervac-homeexchange.com/)
- [IVHE](https://www.ivhe.com/) (geared more around second/vacation homes)

Every one works slightly differently, but many have options that range from simultaneous exchanges (you stay in their home while they stay in yours) to credit-based systems.